# How to Mongodb c# IMongoUpdate lambda Dictionary

Tags: c#, mongodb, lambda

Source

```
public class TB_ACTION_CONTROL
{

    [BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfDocuments)]
    public Dictionary<eACT_TYPE, TB_ACTION> action_list { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
IMongoUpdate update = Update<TB_USER>.Set(c => c.user_act_control.action_list[Key], User.user_act_control.action_list[key]);
```

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to determine the serialization
>   information for the expression: (TB_USER c) =>
>   c.user_act_control.action_list.get_Item(eACT_TYPE.DAILY_CHECK).

occurrence of error

What is the problem?

Comment: The driver can't determine what your expression is supposed to translate to. Go one level deeper and implement the array operations explicitly as you would on the mongo console

Comment: if i change dictionary value, mongodb all update. i want just change value mongodb update.